Miniscript exercise for 3of4 multisig that turns into a 2of4 where 2 specific keys only can spend
I was trying to write this script (miniscript)
or(multi(3,pk(key_1),pk(key_2),pk(key_3),pk(key_4)),and(older(12960),multi(2,pk(key_3),pk(key_4))))
where it's a 3of4 multisig which turns into a 2of4 (only key 3 and key 4) after 90 days..
it gives a "compile error" on bitcoin.sipa.be/miniscript/
I also wrote this:
or(9@thresh(3,pk(key_1),pk(key_2),pk(key_3),pk(key_4)),and(older(12960),thresh(2,pk(key_3),pk(key_4))))
but it gives "duplicate keys" error
what am I doing wrong ?
also, what the correct code would look like?

The second branch is a 2-of-2, not 2-of-4, is that what you want?

yes I want 2 of 2 but specifically only key 3 and 4 must sign

@Ziya_Sadr If you get a compile error, you're not writing Miniscript, but policy language (the compiler on my site compiles policy to Miniscript). "multi" does not exist in the policy language.
